# C++ Qt - Reading specific portion of a text file

Tags: c++, qt, file, qlistwidget

I want to read a specific portion of a text file in a list widget. I have try different ways and looked online for some solutions but I couldn't find much. Im new using Qt but getting along well with it for the most part.

```
QFile YearInfo("C:/Users/Documents/info.txt");
        YearInfo.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text);
        if(YearInfo.isOpen()){
            QTextStream in(&YearInfo);
            bool readEnabled = false;
            QString outputText, startToken = line, endToken = "*"; // line = "2019"
            while(!in.atEnd()){
               QString getLine = in.readLine();
               if(getLine == endToken){
                   readEnabled = false;
               }

               if(readEnabled){
                   outputText.append(getLine + "\n");
               }

               if(getLine == startToken){
                   readEnabled = true;
               }
            }
            ui->listWidget->addItem(outputText);
        }
            YearInfo.flush();
            YearInfo.close();
```

---

Text File contains:

2019
Position    Division    Title   Date        (W.M./R.M./J.R)
*

2020
Position    Division    Title   Date        (P.M./V.R/S.T)
*

Comment: And what's your actual question?

Comment: The program doesn't show the portion of the file. In fact, it shows nothing and I have tried many forms but It seems Im making something wrong. So my question is, why my code doesn't show the portion of the text file?

Comment: Your code seems to be fine and does what you expect it to do.  Try posting a sample of the text file that you are using.  Also double check with the debugger or adding some debug messages with `qWarning()`, that the value of the `startToken` is what you expect and that the file opening is really successful.  Hope this helps =)

Comment: Thanks! I will try it. I'll add the text sample @WilliamSpinelli

Comment: I did not understand your question. You can have no more than one token in each line, which starts from the startToken and ends by endToken. You want to check each readed line for compliance with the template. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: imagine I have a text file that contains many lines. I want to use lines 3 to 8, for example. I dont know how many lines the text file is going to have. I only know that in 'x' line is going to be '2019' and later one with '*'. Both of these lines have only that. I need to print lines 3 (where startToken '2019' is), 4, 5, 6, 7, and 8 (where endToken '*' is) in list widget. Im trying to be as clear as possible in English but that's not my main language lol .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that you have written works as long as you are trying to extract a section of text formatted in the following way

```
2019
Position Division Title   <~~ this line is extracted
Date (W.M./R.M./J.R)      <~~ this line is extracted
More stuff                <~~ this line is extracted
*
```

If you have something formatted in the following way

```
2019 Position Division
Title Date (W.M./R.M./J.R) *
```

```
2019 Position Division Title Date (W.M./R.M./J.R) *
```

nothing will be extracted because you start the extraction when you find a line that contains **only** the `startToken`.  Same thing for the end token.

You could try to modify the `while` loop in your code in the following way

```
while(!in.atEnd()){
    QString getLine = in.readLine().trimmed();

    if(getLine.startsWith(startToken)){
        readEnabled = true;
    }

    if(readEnabled){
        outputText.append(getLine + "\n");
    }

    if(getLine.endsWith(endToken)){
        readEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Now you are checking if the line `startsWith` the `startToken`.  Here I also added a `trimmed` instruction to remove white spaces at the beginning and at the end of each line (just in case...).  The same thing is done with `endsWith` for the `endToken`.

Also it would be best to open the device in read-only mode, since you are not modifying it anyway

```
YearInfo.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
```

and also the `flush` at the end is redundant.

Hope this helps =)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes, I have the text file placing both tokens in separate with nothing else in the lines. Apart from that I will try with the other option you've provide me.

Comment: I'd applied your help and for the most part it worked great. Since I had the text in file correctly placed, I didn't had to use the "startsWith" and "endsWith" (really useful to know for other projects, so thanks). Oh, and the other thing I saw that made the code work 100% was that i use ".trimmed()" like you said, and  in the initialization of "startToken". When checked the text file, startToken looked good to go, no spaces, no nothing besides startToken. Maybe it added some space when saved or something but finally its done. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

To find the entry of a string, I use QRegExp. Please note that since you have a stopToken like a special symbol for QRegExp it might be changed for "\*:

```
#include <QRegExp>
#include <QDebug>

QStringList tokenize(QString line, QString start, QString end)
{
    QRegExp rx(start+".*"+end);
    rx.indexIn(line);
    return rx.capturedTexts();
}

void test()
{
    qDebug()<<tokenize("2019 Position Division Title Date (W.M./R.M./J.R) *", "2019", "\\*");
    // returned ("2019 Position Division Title Date (W.M./R.M./J.R) *")
    qDebug()<<tokenize("2020 Position Division Title Date (P.M./V.R/S.T) *", "2019", "\\*");
    // returned ("")
}
```

Your function must be look like this:

```
...
while(!in.atEnd()){
    QString getLine = in.readLine();
    QStringList strL = tokenize(getLine, startToken, stopToken);
    if (strL.size())
       ui->listWidget->addItem(strL[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        QFile YearInfo("C:/Users/Documents/info.txt");
        YearInfo.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
        if(YearInfo.isOpen()){
            QTextStream in(&YearInfo);
            bool readEnabled = false;
            QString outputText = "", startToken = line.trimmed(), endToken = "*";

            while(!in.atEnd()){
                QString getLine = in.readLine().trimmed();

                if(getLine == startToken){
                    readEnabled = true;
                }

                if(readEnabled){
                    outputText.append(getLine + "\n");
                }

                if(getLine == endToken){
                    readEnabled = false;
                }
            }
            ui->listWidget->addItem(outputText);
        }
            YearInfo.close();
```